# What determines the number of Fists a person has?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017

Clearly, Danny has a single Iron Fist, from the moment he was granted it. He only ever uses a hand, and the same hand, to manifest the Fist.

However, when .

> Davos takes the Fist from him

he ends up with

> *two* Fists.

Clearly, there's no "conservation of Fists" here.

By contrast,

> Colleen

ends up with a single Fist

> Davos

particularly having only one Fist after the ceremony.

Seemingly, in this case, the number of Iron Fists *does* stay constant.

What determines how many Fists a person gets?

Comment: I think the "number of fists" is simply a matter of how proficient one is at using their qi (chi), and Davos (and the Iron Fist seen during Season 1 in the old footage) were more proficient that Danny or Colleen.

Comment: @Derek - Could be. Is there evidence of that in the show? Davos never seemed to be much better than Danny to me, considering that Danny was able to fight him pretty evenly several times, *including* when Davos had the Fist and he didn't. Also, Danny beat him in the test to acquire the Fist, which makes me think that he was roughly as good by whatever measure K'un-L'un uses to test competence for this sort of thing.

Comment: We've never seen them try.

Comment: @Derek - I mean, have we seen any evidence that Davos is more skilled than Danny?

Comment: Someone has to ask the dumb question, so it may as well be me: isn't it possible that Danny and Colleen only have a single dominant hand, so they only use the fist with that hand instinctually, while Davos is ambidextrous?

Comment: What a great question title to see without any connotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the number was conserved the whole time.  Don't forget, in the initial ritual,

> Davos used the body of a previous, dead Iron Fist, as well as stole it from Danny.  I believe one of his fists came from the former Iron Fist, the other came from Danny.

Later, when they try to retrieve the Fist by doing the ceremony in reverse,

> Colleen only had time to retrieve one of the two fists in Davos had.  There was that whole fight when they punch each other and the two fists collide.

However, due to the two Fists being in the same body (this is speculation), one of two things happened:  The two Fists somehow merged just enough into one "power unit", or the ceremony itself required all power be transferred.  Either way, if both Fists did not reside in the same person, they both would die, hence having to complete the ceremony after the big fight.

> Well, at least up until the epilogue scenes.  Maybe they found a way to separate the two Fists again in those months between?

Comment: In season one we see footage of a previous iron fist with two fists. I guess there could be a story behind that.